# Database structure to track item's lifetime events

Tags: php, mysql, database

I would like to be able to track lifetime events of certain item and to be able to reconstruct its state at any time in the past for vizualization purposes. "State" here means a snapshot of several parameters, e.g. location, temperature and being alive/dead. Raw parameter values are recorded/entered only "on change" and independent from each other.

How should I store the parameter **change events** to be able to reconstruct the **state** later?

I can think of two possible solutions:

**Solution 1: "Snapshot" table**

```
+----------+-------------+------+------+
| Location | Temperature | Dead | Time |
+----------+-------------+------+------+
| A        | +           | 0    | 001  |
+----------+-------------+------+------+
| A        | -           | 0    | 002  |
+----------+-------------+------+------+
| B        | +           | 0    | 005  |
+----------+-------------+------+------+
```

On parameter change the state itself is updated and stored. To get a state of an item at a certain point is as simple as fetching one row.

This is exactly what I need, except:

- Redundant data, all parameters are recorded even if only one has changed at the time
- Table has to be altered if attribute set changes in the future
- Knowing when a certain parameter changed is impossible without row comparison

**Solution 2: Recording events**

table stores individual parameters/changes rather than a complete shapshot.

```
+----+-----------+------------+------+
| ID | EventType | EventValue | Time |
+----+-----------+------------+------+
| 1  | loc       | A          | 001  |
+----+-----------+------------+------+
| 2  | temp      | +          | 001  |
+----+-----------+------------+------+
| 3  | temp      | -          | 002  |
+----+-----------+------------+------+
| 4  | loc       | B          | 005  |
+----+-----------+------------+------+
| 5  | temp      | +          | 005  |
+----+-----------+------------+------+
```

While this solution is more flexible than the first, it is problematic to reconstruct the snapshot. For example, how to efficiently check what is the temperature, location and viability at a time 004 in as few DB queries as possible?

Are there other solutions for this problem?

(P.S. This is for a biology experiment web app using php+Doctrine2+MySQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your **Solution 2** you can very easy get everything you need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (t1.eventType),t1.eventValue, t2.* 
FROM `events` AS t1 
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT eventtype, max(time) AS time 
    FROM events 
   WHERE events.`time`<='004'
    GROUP BY eventtype  ) AS t2 
ON t1.eventType=t2.eventType 
WHERE t1.time=t2.time
```

so this query will return all different attribute that was valid for time 004 , and you will see when each of attribute was set

Comment: Thanks, didn't thought it might be done this way. Now I only need to figure out how to implement this in Doctrine2/DQL, but that is a bit off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Your second solution is looking pretty solid. There are other ways to organize the data, such as an field level revision table, which is a touch more structure than you currently have.

Using the second solution you could get a snapshot in one query with a sub-query. I assume this is something that "just needs to be done" and doesn't rely on the most efficient query.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM event
    WHERE time >= '003'
    ORDER BY Time DESC) AS temp
  GROUP BY EventType;
```